# Best way to get MAX customer in my SQL code

Tags: sql, max

Per product, I need to know which customer had the greatest quantity of inventory shipped over a period of time.  I only want 1 customer per product to return in my results.  I know I should be using the MAX on the QtyShip but I can't wrap my head around where.  In a subquery?

I've started with the code below.  Can someone show me where I throw in the max here?

```
Select o.cono ,
o.ProdId ,
o.CustId ,
c.[name] as 'CustomerName' ,
s.shipto ,
s.[name] as 'ShiptoName' ,
s.user15 as 'divno' ,
o.WhseId ,
SUM(NetAmt) as 'totalNet' ,
SUM(cost) as 'totalCost' ,
SUM(QtyShip) as 'totalQtyShip'
FROM Order_Line_Invoice o
LEFT JOIN ARSC c
    on  o.cono = c.cono
        and o.CustId = c.custno
        and c.insx = 1
LEFT JOIN ARSS s
    on  o.cono = s.cono
        and o.CustId = s.custno
        and o.ShipToId = s.shipto
        and s.insx = 1
GROUP BY o.cono ,
o.ProdId ,
o.CustId ,
c.[name] ,
s.shipto ,
s.[name] ,
s.user15 ,
o.WhseId
```

Comment: Which SQL Engine?  With SQL Server, and MySQL 5.7 and higher (I think), you can use Ranking function to do that.

Comment: Hi Danb, that's basically what got it.  Not rank but the row_number since I only wanted 1 result returned whereas rank (i think) or maybe its dense_rank, can bring back multiple records if they have the same scoring criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use row_number() which is supportedby most dbms

```
    with cte as
    (
    Select o.cono ,
    o.ProdId ,
    o.CustId ,
    c.[name] as CustomerName,
    s.shipto ,
    s.[name] as ShiptoName ,
    s.user15 as 'divno ,
    o.WhseId ,
    SUM(NetAmt) as totalNet ,
    SUM(cost) as totalCost ,
    SUM(QtyShip) as totalQtyShip
    FROM Order_Line_Invoice o
    LEFT JOIN ARSC c
        on  o.cono = c.cono
            and o.CustId = c.custno
            and c.insx = 1
    LEFT JOIN ARSS s
        on  o.cono = s.cono
            and o.CustId = s.custno
            and o.ShipToId = s.shipto
            and s.insx = 1
    GROUP BY o.cono ,
    o.ProdId ,
    o.CustId ,
    c.[name] ,
    s.shipto ,
    s.[name] ,
    s.user15 ,
    o.WhseId
    ),
    cte2 as
   (
   select *,row_number()over(partition by ProdId order by totalQtyShip desc) rn
   from cte
 ) select * form cte2 where rn=1
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  I was really going on the wrong track there.  Thanks for the partition tip.

Answer (score 1):

Try
SELECT **top 1** (rest of query here)
and then adding **ORDER BY SUM(QtyShip) Desc** 
to the end